# JPA/Hibernate - How to update limited column of entity through merge

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have one table with 20 columns. Now i want to update only three columns. Is there any way to do the same without using named query as the no of records is too large and the column which need to update has different values in each record.

Answer (score 0):

just to understand,if you have to update only few column,then why you are using merge,just set only those fields in your DAO layer.

```
@Entity
class Employee{

  private String name;

  private String id;

  private String salary;
  // getter setter

}
```

In your DAO layer you can just do like below.

```
Employee emp = (Employee)session.get(Employee.class,id);
emp.setName("test");
```

At the end of transaction,it will be automatically flushed,no need to use merge().